# Deselect a Selected Node in Dynatree

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I am trying to deselect the single selected node in dynatree on a button click. Here is my code :

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnViewAll').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#contents>div').show();
        $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
            node.select(false);
        });
    });
});
```

This code goes through all the nodes but never deselects any anything. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the alternative `deactivate()` :

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getRoot").visit(function(node){
     node.deactivate();
});
```

Hope this helps.